# Office365, give permissions to mailbox for use in Outlook Web App, but not add it to MS Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

A customer of mine has her MS Outlook full of accounts. She needs to check other mail accounts too, so she'd like to access those mailaccounts from Outlook Web App without seeing the same accounts in her MS Outlook.

I cannot give her the passwords of these mail accounts, because the users will occasionally change the passwords, so I need to grand somekind of permission, so she can open the mailbox from OWA.

How can I grand permissions such that she has access to these mailboxes in OWA while not seeing them in her MS Outlook?

Alternatively, if Granting Full Mailbox Access is the only way, is there a way I can ensure that she won't automatically get those mailboxes in her MS Outlook too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, if other users grant you full access of their mailbox, these mailboxes will be automatically mapped to your Outlook profile. You can choose to [turn off automatic mapping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/domain-management/remove-automapping-for-shared-mailbox), and the Outlook client will not automatically obtain these mailboxes. Then you could manually add the shared mailbox which you have been granted permission on the web mail to use.
In addition, granting delegate permissions in Outlook client can also achieve similar features like this. For your reference: [Allow someone else to manage your mail and calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/allow-someone-else-to-manage-your-mail-and-calendar-41c40c04-3bd1-4d22-963a-28eafec25926).

Comment: +1 for the answer. I think this is what I need, but I'm currently away from the office. I'll be able to test this out tomorrow. If all works great, I'll check the answer unless someone posts an even simpler option that does not require powershell. I',m not against Powershell, but I worry that using powershell may cause this to not be visible in the Exchange Admin center, which means we might loose sight of the permissions set at some point.